# How to find where in web app code a GET HTTP request is being issued

Tags: javascript, debugging, get, pycharm

I have a problem with my web app issuing an unexpected GET HTTP request. I have tried stepping through the code with Firefox Firebug but can't see where the GET request is coming from.

In my PyCharm console it is recording the following activity:

```js
[16/Sep/2015 14:52:03] "GET /api/v1/movie/0/get_movie/?_=1442415123105 HTTP/1.1" 201 397
[16/Sep/2015 14:52:03] "GET /static/js/progressbar.min.js.map HTTP/1.1" 404 1688
[16/Sep/2015 14:52:03] "GET /Renowned%20French%20filmmaker%20Nicolas%20Philibert%20(Etre%20et%20Avoir,%20Nenette)%20journeys%20into%20the%20heart%20of%20Radi HTTP/1.1" 404 3500
```

The first two GETs are expected but the third one is not. I need some way to trace the GET request to a line of code. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is an AJAX request, in Chrome you can open Developer Tools (F12), click settings (gear icon), and check the 'Log XMLHttpRequests' checkbox. Next time an AJAX request is made the request will be logged as well as hopefully where it occurs in the JS code.

If you then expand the request in the console, you may see your file/line number as a link that created the request. Click it, and it will go to the line of JS code.